# What is TChart and is this free for monodroid?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, teechart

I am working on monodroid and wanna to have graphs in my application. I have some searches and find this:
[TChart inside LinearLayout generates "width and height must be > 0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192428/tchart-inside-linearlayout-generates-width-and-height-must-be-0)
and this:
http://www.steema.com/teechart/mobile
What is this TChart and whether this is free or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you couldn't find this information on the website you link to yourself?

Quote from your own link:

> The TeeChart for Android Java charting library for Google's Android
>   platform is written in native Android Java and supports most teechart
>   series types including pie chart, line chart, points, area, bar,
>   gauges and maps and 2D,3D formats.

Regarding to the library being free or not, just have a look at the [download page](http://www.steema.com/download/mobile): there's a registered version and evaluation version. The latter is free for download and includes all features of the full version, [but only runs for 50 days](http://www.steema.com/evaluation). I'm sure there'll be license instructions with the downloadable evaluation version too, that further details any possible limitations.